# iOS Swift: a view controller as the root view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I know how to make a view controller the root view controller of the app
by this code:

```
window.rootViewController = (your root view controller())
```

but I saw also this:

```
 instantiateInitialViewController
```

and this:

```
instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)
```

are they the same as rootViewController or they have different functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

- `instantiateInitialViewController` instantiates the view controller marked as initial in a given storyboard. There can be only one initial view controller per storyboard.
- `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` instantiates the view controller with a matching identifier from a given storyboard.

Both methods can be used to instantiate a root view controller, but also non-root view controllers you'd want to present later in the app.

Comment: What is the difference between them and the rootViewController this was my question